# Using ReadXml and Ignore Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have Xml that looks like something like this:

```
<data type="widgets">
   <record>
      <id>1</id>
   </record>
   <record>
      <id>2</id>
   </record>
</data>
```

In the Xml above, the "type" attribute was recently added. Before I added it, I could use DataSet.ReadXml to read the full Xml into a table and then parse out elements I needed from DataSet.Tables[0]. After the attribute was added, DataSet.ReadXml returns no tables. How can I perform the same function with the attribute as I did without it? I am not interested in reading the type attribute into my table.

Comment: Depending on the version of .net and how much code you would need to write, look at XPath or linq.

Comment: Are you really need all those DataSets and DataTables, or linq-to-xml would be fine?

Comment: DataSet.ReadXml returns 2 tables for me. One with "widgets" at Tables[0]. And one with the rest of the data at Tables[1].

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using XPath.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("C:\\blah.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//data//record//id");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
    //do something meaningful
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this problem is to prepare the datatable in advance;

```
string myXml = @"<data type=""widgets"">
    <record>
        <id>1</id>
    </record>
    <record>
        <id>2</id>
    </record>
</data>";

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("record");
dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
ds.Tables.Add(dt);

ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(myXml));
```